Prompt builder, Salesforce
I like to work/practice in prompt builder in my trailhead org and Einstein Analytic dev org. I can't see or access the prompt builder under the Einstein generative AI. Can anyone know or tell me how to access the prompt builder, please?
Screen shot of my analytic training org
